UiPath and Snowflake Native Search (Column Order)
I am using Native Search to pull data from Snowflake in my UiPath automation. I am storing this in a datable. My SF SQL has my fields in a specific order, however, when I run the Native search, the fields are in a random order. How can I order this in my preferred order? Is there a setting?
Below (and attached) is my sample SF query and the results from the datable from Native Search:
Results from Native Search
SELECT LEDGER, ACCOUNT_NK, GL.DESCR, FISCAL_YEAR, ACCT.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD, BOOK_CODE_NK, sum(POSTED_BASE_AMT)
FROM V_PS_LEDGER LEDG
LEFT JOIN D_ACCT_PERIOD ACCT on LEDG.D_ACCT_PERIOD_OID = ACCT.D_ACCT_PERIOD_OID
LEFT JOIN PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL GL on LEDG.PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL_OID = GL.PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL_OID
WHERE FISCAL_YEAR BETWEEN '2020' AND '2024' 
AND ACCT.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5')
AND LEDGER = 'USD'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6;

I read about setting the ordinal using invoke method but I prefer not using another activity.
